# NullPointerException occured while using recursive function in a Client-Server based program - Java

Tags: java, recursion, exception, nullpointerexception, client-server

The program's objective is to print all the directories, sub-directories and files from the folder that we specify on the Client side. This program does that, but in the very end, it throws a NullPointerException. I use a recursive function to print the sub-dirs.

The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Client.main(Client.java:114)

Here is the Client-side program which deals with the listing

```
try{
    File maindir = new File(folder); 
           
    if(maindir.exists() && maindir.isDirectory()) 
    { 
         // array for files and sub-directories  
         // of directory pointed by maindir 
         File arr[] = maindir.listFiles(); 

         System.out.println("Files from main directory : " + maindir); 

         // Calling recursive method 
         RecursivePrint(arr, 0);  
    }
}

catch (NullPointerException e) {
         System.out.println("NPE caught");
}
```

Here is RecursivePrint

```
static void RecursivePrint(File[] arr, int level)  
     { 
         // for-each loop for main directory files 
         for (File f : arr)  
         { 
             // tabs for internal levels 
             for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) 
                 System.out.print("\t"); 
              
             if(f.isFile())  
                 System.out.println(f.getName()); 
               
             else if(f.isDirectory())  
             {  
                 System.out.println("[" + f.getName() + "]"); 
               
                 // recursion for sub-directories 
                 RecursivePrint(f.listFiles(), level + 1); 
             } 
         } 
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out why the NullPointerException occurs and how to resolve it?

Comment: Working with List interface is safer and you can convert your array of File[] to list by using this:

List<File> fileList = Arrays.asList($yourArrayHere$);

Comment: @GaneshGiri List<File> doesn't seem to have methods like getName, isDirectory which are required for this program

Answer (score 0):

The method listFiles() as states in docs "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs." So when you try to print a folder that can't be accessed by current user (such as "System Volume Information" on Windows) you will get a null insted of an array, so your catch clause will be caught. To prevent that you can simply put a check before your internal recursive call like that:

```
            // recursion for sub-directories

            File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null) {
                RecursivePrint(listFiles, level + 1);
            }
```

This will allow you to skip unaccessed folder and proceed with printing.

The other method for dealing with such a problem is to add try-catch block around you internal recursive call like that:

```
            // recursion for sub-directories

            File[] arr1 = f.listFiles();
            try {
                RecursivePrint(arr1, level + 1);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // do something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ran fine for me, but your issue is likely coming from the `f.listFiles()` method call in the line:

```java
RecursivePrint(f.listFiles(), level + 1);
```

Looking at the java docs for that method it reads:

> **Returns** An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null** if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So it seems like `f.listFiles()` might sometimes return null. Which will cause a `NullPointerException` when you try and call any methods on it.

To protect against this you can put a simple null check in place like so:

```java
File[] files = f.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
    RecursivePrint(files, level + 1);
}
```

So your `RecursivePrint` method would now look like:

```
    static void RecursivePrint(File[] arr, int level)
    {
        // for-each loop for main directory files
        for (File f : arr)
        {
            // tabs for internal levels
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
                System.out.print("\t");

            if(f.isFile())
                System.out.println(f.getName());

            else if(f.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("[" + f.getName() + "]");

                // recursion for sub-directories
                File[] files = f.listFiles();
                if (files != null) {
                    RecursivePrint(files, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! The program works without an exception now :)